# Translate Perl to Python: do this or die

Tags: python, perl

I am moving a Perl (of which I have very little knowledge) script to python.

```
$path = $ENV{ 'SOME_NAME' } || die " SOME_NAME ENV VARIABLE NOT FOUND\n";
```

I can (hopefully) see what this line does, either set the variable 'path' to the environment variable 'SOME_NAME' or failing that then print an error message to the user. (Side note: anyone know how to get a search engine to search for special characters like '||'?)

I've tried to implement it in a "pythonic" way (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) using:

```
try:
    path = os.environ['SOME_NAME']
except KeyError,e:
    print "SOME_NAME ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE NOT FOUND\n"
    raise e
```

but this seems rather cumbersome, especially as I'm doing it for 3 different environment variables.

Any ideas if there is a better implementation or would you say this is the "pythonic" way to go about it?

Many Thanks

Comment: About your google question, [google help](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1221265&answer=134479&rd=1): `Generally, punctuation is ignored, including @#$%^&*()=+[]\ and other special characters.` probably can't do much about it

Comment: Thought as much, just wondering if there was a search engine out there that didn't ignore them, would be useful especially when searching for things like this!

Comment: @Jdog You might be able to get something meaningful if you google the name of the character. For expample to search for `||` type "perl vertical bars". If anything, [wikipedia pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_character) on characters and symbols usually list what they are used for in many programming languages.

Comment: Do you think you can get help by *THREATENING US?!!* :)

Comment: @Axeman That's how I read it too. ;) Wait a minute? Is he asking how to search for `||`? **OR?**

Comment: @TLP, it was either that or "So much for the *Benevolent* Dictator for Life!" as if this was marching orders from Guido...which might rankle the Python-supremacists.

Comment: @Axeman I actually had to google that, and I still don't understand it. ;) On a related note, I think we should introduce a "use strict & warnings or die" pragma on all SO questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
try:
    path = os.environ['SOME_NAME']
    var2 = os.environ['VAR2']
    var3 = os.environ['VAR3']
    var4 = os.environ['VAR4']
except KeyError,e:
    print "Not found: ", e
```

You can put more than one statement into a try block.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I needed to separate so that I could tell the user which is missing, but that will be contained in the traceback of the exception of course.. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

What you have there is actually pretty common idiom, and arguably the preferred pattern. Or you just just let the normal exception pass without printing anything extra. Python natively has the same effect. So,

```
path = os.environ["SOME_NAME"]
```

Will just raise a KeyError exception all by itself and the default behavior is to exit on uncaught exceptions. The traceback will show you what and where.

However, you can also provide a default value, if that's possible.

```
path = os.environ.get("SOME_NAME", "/default/value")
```

This will not raise an error and you may do something sensible as a default action.